# How to return href link which are not starting "\listing" using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the links in https://www.panpages.my/search_results?q=

I have written Python script to get all links in each pages
I want to filter the links which is not starting as `"\Listings"`

Please find my script below and help me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from io import StringIO
import csv

data = open("D:/Mine/Python/Projects/Freelancer/seekProgramming/rootpages.csv").read()
dataFile = StringIO(data)
csvReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
f = open('paylinks.csv', 'w', newline = '')
writer = csv.writer(f)

for row in csvReader:
    myurl = row[0]
    def simple_web_scrapper(url):
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for root in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "mid_section col-xs-10 col-sm-7 tmargin xs-nomargin"}):
            for link in root.findAll('a'):
                href = link.get('href')
                print(href)
    simple_web_scrapper(myurl)
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in csvReader:
    myurl = row[0]
    def simple_web_scrapper(url):
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for root in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "mid_section col-xs-10 col-sm-7 tmargin xs-nomargin"}):
            for link in root.findAll('a'):
                href = link.get('href')
                if href.startswith('\listings'): #that's the row you need
                    print(href)
    simple_web_scrapper(myurl)
```

Comment: @Saranaone, any feedback? was my answer helpful?